# How to divide the input of a variable when it reaches its maximum length

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

> I am writing a procedure which takes the body of other procedures and
>   stores them locally in my device as a text file.

It works correctly except when I am using a large procedure in which case it will be truncated. Note am using **nvarchar(max)** .
Any suggestion to solve the problem?

This is part of procedure :

```
 DECLARE @V_STRING  NVARCHAR(MAX)=''
 DECLARE @V_Table TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),LINE NVARCHAR(MAX))
IF @V_TYPE ='P'--PROCEDURES
     BEGIN
         SET @V_PATH=@V_PATH+'4.PROCEDURES'
         EXECUTE SP_CreateFolder @V_PATH,@P_DataBase
         SET @V_TYPE='\CREATE PROCEDURES'+'.sql'
         SET @V_STRING='USE ['+@P_NewDB+'];
         GO
         IF EXISTS (SELECT name from sys.objects where name='''+@P_ObjectName+''' AND TYPE=''P'')
         BEGIN
         DROP PROCEDURE ' +@P_ObjectName +' 
         END
         GO'
    END
         SET @V_CheckType='USE '+@P_DataBase+'; EXECUTE SP_HELPTEXT '+@V_Objec --@v_object refer to the name of procedure and @P_DataBase refer to database which the procedure belong
             INSERT INTO @V_Table (LINE)--get the body of given object and store in variable table by using sp_HELPTEXT dictionary
                EXECUTE (@V_CheckType)

             INSERT INTO @V_Table (LINE) 
                VALUES ('    GO  ')


             SELECT @V_STRING=@V_STRING+LINE FROM @V_Table
             Execute SP_WriteToFile @V_PATH , @V_STRING --this procedure will create a text file in the path just created
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sp_helptext returns multiple rows of 255 characters each (if the definition is over 255 characters);
Try using sys.sql_modules or OBJECT_DEFINITION instead, the definitions will be in a single row then, and much easier to work with:

```
     SET @V_STRING='USE ['+@P_NewDB+']';

     SET @V_CheckType='USE '+@P_DataBase+'; select definition from sys.sql_modules where object_id = object_id('''+@V_Objec + ''')' --@v_object refer to the name of procedure and @P_DataBase refer to database which the procedure belong
         INSERT INTO @V_Table (LINE)--get the body of given object and store in variable table by using sp_HELPTEXT dictionary
            EXECUTE (@V_CheckType)


         SELECT @V_STRING=@V_STRING+LINE + CHAR(10) + 'GO' FROM @V_Table

         --SELECT @V_STRING

         Execute SP_WriteToFile @V_PATH , @V_STRING
```

Comment: But the problem still there when i assign the result to the variable it will be cut off

Comment: @DANAA added example to the answer

Comment: @DANAA actually, something else to check - what is the definition of the parameters in SP_WriteToFile ? If that's not declared as nvarchar(max) you may get truncation there.